# retrofit2.HttpException thrown even though it was handled in onError

Tags: java, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm always getting an unhandled exception when google+ responses with error json

```
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 404 
                         at retrofit2.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$SimpleCallAdapter$1.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:159)
                         at retrofit2.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$SimpleCallAdapter$1.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:154)
                         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
                         at retrofit2.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:109)
                         at retrofit2.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:88)
                         at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                         at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                         at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
                         at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
                         ....
```

In that code:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> strSub) {
            // Getting ID
            strSub.onNext(AccountUtils.getAccountId(appContext));
            strSub.onCompleted();})

          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          // Get Google+ Image through Retrofit2
          .flatMap(str -> createGPlusUserObservable(str, AccountUtils.ANDROID_API_KEY))
          .map(this::setprofileImage)    // I don't see Timber.d message inside that method!
          .compose(binder)
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(subscriber);
```

In createGPlusUserObservable I use Retrofit 2 to get google+ image

```
private Observable<GPlusUser> createGPlusUserObservable(String userId, String apiKey) {
    //try {
    GoogleApiService service = ServiceFactory.getInstance().createJsonRetrofitService(
            GoogleApiService.class,
            GoogleApiService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT
    );

    Observable<GPlusUser> result = service.getGPlusUserInfo(userId, apiKey);
    Timber.d("Here1!"); // I see that in console!
    return result;  // It always returns result!
    /*} catch (Throwable e) { - it doesn't catch anything!
        Timber.d("Here!");
    }*/
}
```

And subscriber is:

```
new Subscriber<GPlusUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Timber.d("GPlusUserSubscriber ON COMPLETED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if (e instanceof HttpException) {
                Timber.d("RETROFIT!"); // I see that in console!
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(GPlusUser gPlusUser) {
            setupAccountBox();
        }
    };
```

UPDATE: setprofileImage method

```
private GPlusUser setprofileImage(GPlusUser gPlusUser) {
    Timber.d("FOUR"); // As I've said, it doesn't appear in console
    AccountUtils.setProfileImage(appContext, gPlusUser.image.url);
    Timber.d("Setting profile image: %s", gPlusUser.image.url);
    return gPlusUser;
}
```

So the question is - why I'm getting unhandled exception if I handle it in subscriber's onError(Throwable e)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code for `setprofileImage'?

Comment: See the UPDATE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because error happens in retrofit factory logic, while converting from pure html string to my GPlusUser class.

I've eliminated that annoying exception in console log by working with pure html through `Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> response` and it's `response.isSuccess()`